# In Magento 1.9, how can I set a custom field for an order?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, custom-field

I need to have one more additional field for each order. I can add this attribute with this code:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$setup->addAttribute('order', 'order_dropship_export_status', array(
        'position'          => 1,
        'type'              => 'text',
        'label'             => 'order_dropship_export_status',
        'global'            => 1,
        'visible'           => 1,
        'required'          => 0,
        'user_defined'      => 1,
        'searchable'        => 0,
        'filterable'        => 0,
        'comparable'        => 0,
        'visible_on_front'  => 1,
        'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
        'unique'            => 0,
        'is_configurable'   => 0,
        'position'          => 1,

));

$installer->endSetup();
```

and the field is added to the eav_attribute table in Magento. However, when I set it using:

```
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order") -> load($a_ids[0]);
$order -> setOrderDropshipExportStatus("XXXXXX");
$order -> save();
```

it is not saved anywhere. Where and how can I save this attribute for an order?

Comment: sir you want this new `custom-field` in backend or in invoice or in both.

Comment: I want to have it anywhere in database. No matter where. I just have to get it somehow later, from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your config.xml settings? Make sure the settings correct.

MyPack/CustomStatus/etc/config.xml

```
<global> 
    <resources>
        <customstatus_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>MyPack_CustomStatus</module>
                <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </customstatus_setup>
        <customstatus_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </customstatus_write>
        <customstatus_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </customstatus_read>
    </resources>
     <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote>                           
            <order_dropship_export_status><to_order>*</to_order></order_dropship_export_status>
        </sales_convert_quote>

        <sales_convert_order>                                              
            <order_dropship_export_status><to_quote>*</to_quote></order_dropship_export_status>
        </sales_convert_order>
    </fieldsets>
</global>
```

MyPack/CustomStatus/sql/customstatus_setup/install-1.1.0.php

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("order", "order_dropship_export_status", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "order_dropship_export_status", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Now you can access this custom filed by using:

```
//set value
$order->setData('order_dropship_export_status', 'Your Value');
$order->save();

//get value
$order->getData('order_dropship_export_status');
```

Comment: Hi I don't even remember how I solved this. But I will accep your answer because it seems correct.